# Flask app has ModuleNotFoundError when using Alpine, nginx, and uwsgi.. but with flask run it works fine

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, uwsgi

I've written a small flask app, which runs fine on my Windows 10 desktop using `flask run`, and also runs fine on an Alpine Linux 3.14 Docker container using `flask run`, but when I use nginx and uwsgi, I receive a `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_cffi_backend'` error. I have run through all the other articles on stackoverflow which fit this description, to no avail.

From `python --version` I am running `Python 3.9.7`, which has been installed using the official `python:3.9-alpine3.14` container from Docker Hub. I have also added the following `apk add --no-cache python3-dev gcc libc-dev libffi-dev uwsgi-python3 jpeg-dev zlib-dev git nano`

***Here is the full error from the uwsgi log***

```
uWSGI running as root, you can use --uid/--gid/--chroot options
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI as root !!! (use the --uid flag) ***
spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 109)
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 110, cores: 2)
spawned uWSGI worker 2 (pid: 111, cores: 2)
bcrypt is required to use Flask-Bcrypt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/./run.py", line 4, in <module>
    from ticketsapi import create_app
  File "/app/./ticketsapi/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from flask_bcrypt import Bcrypt
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask_bcrypt.py", line 27, in <module>
    raise e
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask_bcrypt.py", line 24, in <module>
    import bcrypt
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/bcrypt/__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    from . import _bcrypt  # type: ignore
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_cffi_backend'
unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') (callable not found or import error)
*** no app loaded. GAME OVER ***
SIGINT/SIGQUIT received...killing workers...
Exception ignored in: <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python3.9/threading.py'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/./run.py", line 4, in <module>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 1388, in _shutdown
    from ticketsapi import create_app
  File "/app/./ticketsapi/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from playhouse.flask_utils import FlaskDB
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/playhouse/flask_utils.py", line 12, in <module>
    from playhouse.db_url import connect as db_url_connect
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/playhouse/db_url.py", line 7, in <module>
    from playhouse.cockroachdb import CockroachDatabase
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1004, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 157, in __enter__
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 196, in _get_module_lock
KeyboardInterrupt
unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') (callable not found or import error)
*** no app loaded. GAME OVER ***
    def _shutdown():
KeyboardInterrupt:
```

***The output from pip freeze***

```
backports.entry-points-selectable==1.1.0
bcrypt==3.2.0
blinker==1.4
certifi==2021.10.8
cffi==1.15.0
click==8.0.3
cryptography==35.0.0
distlib==0.3.3
dnspython==2.1.0
email-validator==1.1.3
filelock==3.3.1
Flask==2.0.2
Flask-Bcrypt==0.7.1
Flask-Login==0.5.0
Flask-Mail==0.9.1
Flask-WTF==0.15.1
idna==3.3
itsdangerous==2.0.1
Jinja2==3.0.2
MarkupSafe==2.0.1
peewee==3.14.4
Pillow==8.4.0
platformdirs==2.4.0
pycparser==2.20
PyMySQL==1.0.2
python-dotenv==0.19.1
six==1.16.0
supervisor==4.2.2
virtualenv==20.9.0
Werkzeug==2.0.2
WTForms==2.3.3
```

***My nginx conf***

```
server {
    listen 5000;

    location /static {
        alias /app/ticketsapi/static;
    }

    location / {
        uwsgi_pass unix:///app/socket/uwsgi.sock;
        include /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params;
        # proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

***My uwsgi ini***

```
## Application
##
module = run:app
chdir=/app
socket = /app/socket/uwsgi.sock
chown-socket = nginx:nginx
chmod-socket = 777
processes = 5
threads = 2


## General
##
strict = true
master = true
enable-threads = true
vacuum = true
single-interpreter = true
die-on-term = true
need-app = true
lazy-apps = true
```

I've been working on resolving this for a couple of days now, and I am stumped. How can I resolve this error and move forward with my project?

Comment: Have you tried adding `pkg-config`? The [installation instructions mention it](https://cffi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#platform-specific-instructions) as important, otherwise try the same instructions for manually building+installing it from source.

Comment: @Cobalt I've manually built and installed cffi and bcrypt, but still the same. The app runs fine with ```flask run``` and ```python run.py``` but not ```uwsgi```

Comment: Have you checked if the dir where cffi is located is part of your `PYTHONPATH`? Otherwise, you should consider opening an issue in the repository.

Comment: While going through logs, rebuilding my container, etc. I noticed two slightly different versions of Python (3.9.7 and 3.9.5). So I've setup a venv for my app, and it now works.

Comment: Don't use Alpine as your base unless you have an excellent reason to. https://pythonspeed.com/articles/alpine-docker-python/

Comment: @AKX I've been working myself around to the same conclusion, simply in terms of tracking down obscure runtime bugs (which ubuntu already has most of the questions answered).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By going through the various logs, I noticed that there were references to two slightly different versions of Python, namely 3.9.5 and 3.9.7.

Although I'm using Alpine Linux 3.14, I used this [Digital Ocean tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-20-04) to resolve my issue by employing a Python Virtual Environment (venv).